# Refer "this" to custom variable

Tags: javascript, this

I am making something like this:

```
var talkAPI = {
    init: function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            this.speak();
        },1000);
    },
    speak: function(){
         //Something else
    }
};
```

However, I found this is not working as I expected. So I did some tests, and I found out that `this` in the `setInterval` is referring to the `Window`. And this is not I wanted. So how can I re-refer `this` to `talkAPI`? Because I don't want to do this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    window.talkAPI.speak();    //Not so good
},1000);
```

Comment: Why not just use `talk.speak()`? Same length as `this.speak()` and more reliable ;)

Comment: @Kolink — It depends on the object being

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It was `talk` when we posted, it was edited :p

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I fixed it. (in my question)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Woot, didn't see that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to save the original `this` for use in the callback

```
init: function() {
    var self = this;
    setInterval(function(){
        self.speak();
    },1000);
},
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the simple and easy way. Also worth mentioning the new ES5 feature [`Function#bind`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5). And some theory would be good, such as: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html). ;-) (Disclaimer: That links to my blog. But it doesn't have ads.)

Comment: Yea, this might be the easiest way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @Derek: Actually, in this specific case, the *easiest* way is the way Kolink mentioned in his comment, because in this specific case, you're dealing with a singleton object. But Jared's answer is the way you normally do it, in cases where the `init` function might be shared by multiple objects -- **and** it works with singletons *too*, so it's the way most of us would probably do it, for future-proofing and just because the idiom is familiar.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that in JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by *how* a function is called, not where it's defined (as it is in other languages with that keyword). So the way that `setInterval` calls the function you give it, `this` is not set to anything specific (and so defaults to the global object, which is `window` on browsers). More here: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

With the code you've quoted, you have two options:

1. As Kolink commented, since your object is a singleton and the `init` function closes over the `talkAPI` variable, there's no reason whatsoever you can't just use `talkAPI`:

   ```
   var talkAPI = {
       init: function(){
           setInterval(function(){
               talkAPI.speak();    // <=== Only change is here
           },1000);
       },
       speak: function(){
            //Something else
       }
   };
   ```
2. The more general answer, which works both with singletons and with objects created by constructor functions and such, is to preserve the value of `this`, [as described by JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307068/157247):

   ```
   var talkAPI = {
       init: function(){
           var self = this;        // <=== Create a variable to close over
           setInterval(function(){
               self.speak();    // <=== Use it
           },1000);
       },
       speak: function(){
            //Something else
       }
   };
   ```

In both cases, the functions have an enduring, live link to the symbols they close over, which is why they can use them. Functions that have data bound to them in that way are called *closures*. More here: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)